# Select rows in sap.ui.table.Table Control

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

Is there a way to select the number of shown rows in a [sap.ui.table.Table](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.table.Table.html#constructor) like shown in the bottom-right corner of the picture below?

[image: sap.ui.table]

Also my first column doesn't show checkboxes at the first column for multiselection. Multiselect does work, but I want checkboxes in the first column for it. How to do that?

I've set the attribute:

`selectionMode : sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.Multi,`

[image: multiselect doesn't work]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to achieve this: [embed.plnkr.co/NQpkJo/](https://embed.plnkr.co/NQpkJo/?show=view%2FTable.view.xml,preview)

- In order to change the number of shown rows, you need to add the property **[`visibileRowCount`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Table/methods/setVisibleRowCount)** to your table which you could manipulate via data binding from single-click controls like [sap.m.StepCount](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.StepInput/preview) or [sap.m.Slider](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.Slider/preview).
- The [selection mode](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Table/methods/setSelectionMode) `"MultiToggle"` provides an additional column to select rows, which even enables us to select all of them if needed.
  The value `"Multi"` [is deprecated](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.SelectionMode) since UI5 version 1.38.